# Combine NumPy Arrays by Reference

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reference, pygame

I want to combine two arrays into a new array in O(1).  Then, I want to change the values in this new array to change the values in the old arrays.

This is in the context of PyGame's surfarray module, which does not have a function that returns an RGBA (n*m*4) array--only RGB (n*m*3) and A (n*m) arrays separately.  Ideally, I would create a new array "RGBA" in O(1) that references the "RGB" and "A" arrays.  Changing "RGBA" would change both "RGB" and "A", and so change the surface.

I don't know if this is possible, since I can't think of a way to do it with C.  However, I can think of some ideas.  For example, maybe there's a numpy array type that encapsulates some subarrays, and internally redirects indexing to the correct one at the C level.  This would be fine.

Comment: I'm not familiar with PyGame, but from a quick look at the docs, it seems to internally keep RGBA values as 2D array's of 32 bit ints. Have you tried if using `pixels2d` and modifying the 8 MSB (or LSB, not sure which) of your resulting array gets what you are after?

Comment: The only way I know of doing this would be to subclass `ndarray` - See http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html

Comment: If by RGBA, you mean a continuous block of memory, when starting from a two independent blocks (RGB and A as returned by PyGame), then there's no way to do this in O(1).  But why do you need RGBA to be a single array?  Or, can you start with a continuous block RGBA and give this to PyGame in two pieces (RGB and A)?

Comment: Jaime: that's a great idea; I had thought that it returned an array of RGB triples, but it seems it returns a 2D array of RGBA ints.  tom10: the array needs to be in one piece because it's going to a callback that needs it.  So, is there a way to get the 2D array of RGBA ints as a 3D array of bytes in O(1)?

Comment: @IanMallett, Try `rgba.view(uint8).reshape(4,m,n)`

Comment: @AndrewMarshall It would actually be the other way around, `rgba.view(uint8).reshape(rgba.shape + (4,))`, but yes, that would be the way.

Comment: The .reshape creates a new array, so I'm using .resize instead.  It's actually harder because the pixels that pixels2D returns are an array of columns, not vice versa.  Anyway, for people of the future, the code to create a BGRA array is: http://pastebin.com/KLgsFFrU.  It would be nice to make it RGBA, maybe there's a way to get a view for that too?

Comment: @IanMallett Try taking a view of your original array with reversed endianess, either with `dtype` `'<u4'` or `'>u4`, before taking the `uint8` view. It probably won't work unless you copy the array, but it may be worth trying.

Comment: Didn't seem to have an effect one way or the other.  But wouldn't reversing endianness make it ARGB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own class that will manage the referencing procedures, as shown in the example below. You should work further on this to include slicing capabilities with `__getslice__`, `__add__`, `__mul__`, and so forth.

```
import numpy as np
a1 = np.arange(1,11)
a2 = np.arange(101,111)
class Combiner():
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.arrays = [arg for arg in args]
        self.lens = [len(arg) for arg in args]
    def __getitem__(self,i):
        if i >=0:
            shift = 0
            acc = 0
            for j,l in enumerate(self.lens):
                acc += l
                if i<acc:
                    return self.arrays[j][i-shift]
                shift += l
        if i<0:
            shift = 0
            acc = 0
            for j in xrange(len(self.lens)-1,-1,-1):
                l = self.lens[j]
                acc -= l
                if i>=acc:
                    return self.arrays[j][i+shift]
                shift += l

    def __setitem__(self,i,v):
        if i >=0:
            shift = 0
            acc = 0.
            for j,l in enumerate(self.lens):
                acc += l
                if i<acc:
                    self.arrays[j][i-shift] = v
                    return
                shift += l
        if i<0:
            shift = 0
            acc = 0
            for j in xrange(len(self.lens)-1,-1,-1):
                l = self.lens[j]
                acc -= l
                if i>=acc:
                    self.arrays[j][i+shift] = v
                    return
                shift += l

a3 = Combiner(a1,a2)
print a3[-10]
# 101
a3[-2] = 22222
a3[ 4] = 11111
print a1
#[    1     2     3     4 11111     6     7     8     9    10]
print a2
#[  101   102   103   104   105   106   107   108 22222   110]
```

Comment: I think the reason I didn't accept this answer at the time was that it is inelegant, and I was hoping for a more Pythonic answer. Internally, of course, it would have to do something like this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I've completely understood the question. From my knowledge, pygame surfaces are in RGBA (to be exact, BGRA) contiguous arrays if you init pygame and surfaces like this (note "32" in each line):

```
# display surface
DISP = pygame.display.set_mode((window_w, window_h), 0, 32)
# some surface
window = pygame.Surface((w, h), 0, 32)
```

Also I would recommend to use 32 bit when possible, and not 24 bit, because 24 bit surfaces are hard to interoperate with arrays (I use `numpy` for storing and manipulating image data).
For example, a 24 bit surface **must** have amount of pixel dividable by 4, if I am not mistaken.

As said, I am not sure what is your final task, but here is how I do it.
E.g. load an image with `openCV` lib and convert it to BGRA array:

```
# BGR 3d numpy array array (shape = h, w, 3) with image data
img = cv2.imread(filename)
# BGRA 3d numpy array (shape = h, w, 4) 
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
```

Then this function copies whole array data into a surface, just need to be sure they have same pixel size:

```
# copy array data into a pygame surface
def copy_arr(surface, myarray):
    bv = surface.get_buffer()
    bv.write(myarray.tostring(), 0)
```

But it can be that you wanted to do something else.

Comment: This question is pretty old, and I don't remember what I wanted to do either. It looks like it was to make an RGBA wrapper around two arrays--one RGB and the other A. So this doesn't really help.

Comment: @imallett ok, nevermind. I just thought maybe you overcomplicate some easy task. Usually if one need to manipulate pixel data, it is better to have the data in array and not create a reference from a surface. Surfaces are more suited for pygame's own functions like rotozoom, etc.

Comment: Right, and the problem is that I have two separate arrays, instead of one. FYI: surfaces _are_ actually arrays. That's what pixelarray does: expose the backing store.