# Using Array to Store Pixels of Window

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pixel

Is it possible (in terms of performance) to have a single multi-dimensional array that contains one 8-bit integer per pixel, for each pixel in the game window? I need to update the game window in a timely manner based on this array.

I'm aiming for something like the following:

```
import numpy
window_array = numpy.zeros((600, 600), dtype=numpy.int8)

#draw the screen
for (y, x), value in numpy.ndenumerate(window_array):
    if value == 1:
        rgb = (0, 0, 0)
    elif value == 2:
        rgb = (50, 50, 50)
    blit_pixel(x, y, rgb)
```

I'd like to be going 30-60 FPS, but so far my tests have yielded results that were much too slow to run at even a bad framerate. Is it possible to do, and if so, how?

Comment: You should have a look at how OpenCV's python module works - the cv2 module. It think it uses numpy arrays of (R, G, B) tuples

Comment: Is there no way to do it with something like pygame or pyglet?

Comment: I haven't used pygame/pyglet. This is just a suggestion that you should explore how cv2 works and see if pygame does something similar :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used pygame, so take my anwser with a grain of salt...

That said, it seems very unlikely that you are going to get any decent frame rate if you are iterating over 360,000 pixels with a python loop and doing a python function call at each one.

I learned from [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14206938/combine-numpy-arrays-by-reference) (read the comment thread) that the [`pygame.surfarray`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surfarray.html) module will give you a reference to the array holding the actual screen data. `pygame.surfarray.pixels3d` should return a reference to an array of shape `(rows, cols, 3)` where the last dimension holds the RGB values on screen. With that reference, you can change the pixels on screen directly, without needing a python loop doing something like:

```
import numpy
surf_array = pygame.surfarray.pixels3d(surface)
window_array = numpy.zeros(surf_array.shape[:2], dtype=numpy.int8)
...
surf_array[numpy.nonzero(window_array == 1)] = np.array([0, 0, 0])
surf_array[numpy.nonzero(window_array == 2)] = np.array([50, 50, 50])
```

Not sure if a call to `pygame.display.update` is needed to actually show your changes, but this approach will sustain a much, much higher frame rate than what you had in mind.