# How to present Gabor patches on screen in Pygame / Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I've been trying to figure out a way to present Gabor patches onto a black background on pygame, and have struggled to do so. I can generally do each element independently - so a) I can make a black background screen appear, and b) I can run this bunch of code separately and get a Gabor patch to appear on its own separate screen:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

size = np.linspace(-np.pi,np.pi,200)
xgrid, ygrid = np.meshgrid(size, size)

gaussian = np.exp(-(xgrid/2)**2-(ygrid/2)**2) 
sine = np.sin(xgrid*10)
gabor = sine * gaussian
plt.imshow(gabor,cm.gray) 
plt.show()
```

But what I would like to is to be able to make a Gabor patch appear in a pre-determined location on the black Pygame screen itself. I've watched a few youtube tutorials on presenting images in Pygame and have tried the following method (no success):

```
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics
import sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import time
pygame.init()
Clock= pygame.time.Clock()
FPS =30
screenWidth=GetSystemMetrics(0)
screenHeight=GetSystemMetrics(1)
fullScreenSize=(screenWidth/2,screenHeight/2) 
gameDisplay=pygame.display.set_mode(fullScreenSize)
BLACK = (0,0,0)

while True:

for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT or event.type == KEYUP:
            pygame.quit()


size = np.linspace(-np.pi,np.pi,200)
xgrid, ygrid = np.meshgrid(size, size)
gaussian = np.exp(-(xgrid/2)**2-(ygrid/2)**2) 
sine = np.sin(xgrid*10)  
gabor = sine * gaussian

x = ((screenWidth/2) * 0.3) #Left on the x-axis
y = ((screenHeight/2) * 0.45) #Mid-height on screen

#MY ATTEMPT TO SPECIFY A GABOR THAT IS TO BE PRESENTED ON THE LEFT SIDE OF THE SCREEN
def LeftGabor (x,y): 
gameDisplay.blit(gabor,(x,y))


gameDisplay.fill(BLACK)
gameDisplay.blit(gabor,(x,y))

LeftGabor(x,y)
pygame.display.update()
Clock.tick(FPS)
```

Using this code, all that happens is that a black screen pops up. Nothing else. Could someone please point out what I'm doing wrong and point me in the right direction?

Comment: -1 :  your code is not formatted (indents), it is hard to read and contains a lot of not relevant info. You can indeed render numpy arrays in pygame, there are some similar questions about how to do it, see for example [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14206938/combine-numpy-arrays-by-reference/36535866#36535866)

Answer (score 0):

Your gabor object is not a blittable object. From what I can make out it is an array with co-orinates and values for each co-ordinte, where the co-ordinates run from minus pi to pi, and there are 200 in each direction.  you neede to map these to the screen, and everywehere there is a point, draw it usinhg the pygame.draw.line function.